# CSS Flip Letter Horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to create a small project where a user enters in a word (preferably a palindrome) and the second half is flipped. Like the good ol' [ABBA logo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/ABBA_logo.png) but the other way around.

I have been reading quite a few pages but none have satisfied my need. I thought about using SVG's `<text>` element but I didn't quite understand some things about it.

Basically, my expected output would be something like this:

[image: Expected]

This is just a dodgy image I whipped up and it's not a great example because a B rotated 180 degrees can look like one flipped horizontally depending on the font.

What I'm basically asking is, is what I'm after achievable with CSS and/or JavaScript?

Comment: transform: rotateY(180deg);?

Comment: @spedwards it is - have you tried anything?

Comment: @easwee I had tried every solution I'd looked at and I only just realised that my problem was that I hadn't been setting `display` to `inline-block`

Comment: @easwee Closed? Really? This is blatantly and bafflingly stupid; remove the close status. +1 for asking a good, intelligent and very specific question.

Comment: @John don't be silly - it's a how to question that shows no effort or code trying to achieve desired behavior and has no MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @easwee And that kind of attitude is why I've deleted many of my questions and posted them on my own blog instead: not everyone knows what to use and it does *not* inherently make that person lazy.

Comment: @John That is really irrelevant info to me. "Give me the code" questions are not welcome on SO. I'll stop the debate here - you can complain on meta if you think this question deserves to be opened.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```css
.fliph {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleX(-1); /* Or also:   rotateY(180deg) */
}
```

```html
A<span class="fliph">B</span>BA
```

Comment: Thanks. Prior to asking this question I had no idea why none of the solutions were working. Then I realised I'd left out `display:inline-block`

Comment: @Spedwards yes, an element needs other than `inline` in order to apply transforms. You're welcome, happy coding.

Comment: Yeh. Complete brain fart haha. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<b>A<div class = "rotate">B</div>BA</b>
```

Multi Browser supported plus you can rotate the text at different angles..

Answer (score 1):

try this. i think transformation of text done by only CSS. no need JS.

```css
.flip {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<span>ABCD</span><span class="flip">ABCD</span>
```